# VBA Find if an array (made up of range) contains a specific value

Tags: arrays, vba, range

I'm trying to write a code which takes a specific predefined, hardcoded value and a range made up of values from 3rd to last column with value (just one row) and sees if my array contains that specific item. The code I have:

```
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = Cells(Cells.Find("Parameters", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim Environment
Environment = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Specification").Range(Cells(Cells.Find("Environment").Row, 3), Cells(Cells.Find("Environment").Row, LastColumn)).Value

If ItemIsInArray(Environment , "SKIN") Then
'do stuff
End if
```

And the function

```
Function ItemIsInArray(arr As Variant, arrX As Variant) As Boolean
   
'Declare variables
Dim i As Long, j As Long, boolFound As Boolean, mtch

'Main function
If Not IsArray(arrX) Then
    For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If CStr(arr(j)) = CStr(arrX) Then ItemIsInArray = True: Exit For
    Next j
    Exit Function
End If
   
For i = LBound(arrX) To UBound(arrX, 2)
    For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If CStr(arr(j)) = CStr(arrX(1, i)) Then
            boolFound = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next j
        
If boolFound Then ItemIsInArray = True: Exit Function
    boolFound = False
Next i

ItemIsInArray = False

End Function
```

Problem is that it returns "subscript out of range" on
"CStr(arr(j))" in "If CStr(arr(j)) = CStr(arrX) Then ItemIsInArray = True: Exit For".

I guess the problem is the way how I convert the range to an array, but I can't seem to figure it out. Could someone help me solve this?

Comment: Your array is 2-dimensional and you're only passing a single dimension in your indexer (`arr(j)`). You need to loop over both dimensions and use the `LBound(array, dimension)` and `UBound(array, dimension)` overloads.

Comment: That's probably the problem. If you post an answer - I will be happy to accept it

Comment: BTW since you are doing only one row, you can use Application.Match: `Dim t: t=application.match("SKIN",Environment ,0)` then `If Not IsError(t) then`  This will not work if more than one row or one column in the array.

Comment: BTW2, see [THIS](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/#:~:text=You%20can%20see%20that%20Find,number%20of%20XY%20pairs%20found.&text=This%20is%20because%20there%20is,faster%20than%20the%20Variant%20array.) article.  It shows that match is quicker for a single search, but variant arrays are quicker if there are multiple searches needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is 2-dimensional and you're only passing a single dimension in your indexer: `arr(j)`.

You need to loop over both dimensions and use the `LBound(array, dimension)` and `UBound(array, dimension)` overloads.

Something like the following:

```
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If CStr(arr(i, j)) = CStr(arrX) Then ItemIsInArray = True: Exit For
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: You have a mistake in your code. instead of "2," it must be "2)"